# Excel VBA Function Giving # Value Error when trying to use in Excel formulas

Tags: excel, function, vba

I am using the below code to remove vowels from a text and when i run it using VBA it works fine. 
But when i use the same formula =RMV(Text) in Excel it gives me an Error #Value.
Below is the code, pls Help

---

```
Function RMV(Text) As String
'RMV = RemoveVowels
Dim I As Long
Dim J As Long
Dim Ws As Worksheet
Dim Cell As Range

Set Ws = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("sheet1")
I = 2
J = 1
Lastrow = Ws.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row

For I = 2 To Lastrow  '' For Loop to cover all the cells in the range
    RMV = ""
    If Ws.Cells(I, 1) <> "" Then ''If condition to select each cell
        Text = Ws.Cells(I, 1)  '' Assigning the cell Value to variable Text
        For J = 1 To Len(Text) '' FOR loop to go scan each letter in the Text
            If Not UCase(Mid(Text, J, 1)) Like "[AEIOU]" Then 
                RMV = RMV & Mid(Text, J, 1) 
            End If
        Next J
            Lastrow1 = Ws.Cells(Rows.Count, 2).End(xlUp).Row 
            Cells(I, 2) = RMV 
    End If
Next I

End Function
```

---

Answer (score 1):

`Cells(I, 2) = RMV` is your problem. During a function, you **cannot** write directly back to the worksheet (otherwise the calculation process would break).

The only thing you can do is to set `RMV` to the adjusted string. That is returned to the worksheet.

Comment: Thanks for the Help, I am new to VBA Macros, Can u please help me how to set RMV to the Adjusted string.